# Win 10 recovery partition gone - PC wont recognise other boot media

Tags: windows-10, boot

So, I botched something and in the end deleted the recovery partition on a brand new Acer Aspire X XC-885. The PC wont boot without that partition.

At the same time it does not recognise other boot media (both USB with Win10 install media and other SSD with Win10 already installed). Even after removing the originally installed SSD "chip" no other boot media show up in the Bios.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Extension: Bios does realise there is another SSD connected, but I cannot choose to boot from it.

Comment: can you clarify if you made any changes in the bios section earlier...

Comment: Call Acer and ask for recovery media.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I got it. Disabled secure boot & then changed from UEFI to legacy, then the SSD showed up.